# Converting to two's complement in python

Tags: python, binary, twos-complement

I have a motion controller that needs to get 4 bytes of data as the setpoint position.

The format is int32_t in C which is a 32 bit 2's complement number. The main issue is the formatting the number with the leading zeros.

I found this solution which works for positive numbers:

```
binary = '{:032b}'.format(n)
bytes = [chr(int(binary[i*8:(i*8)+8],2)) for i in range(4)]
```

Then I can send these 4 bytes over USB serial to the motion controller. However there is a big issue with negative numbers in this case. I'm not sure if there's an easy way to convert the number into 32 bit 2's complement and then split up the bytes to be sent over serial. Python is a much higher level language so unfortunately it doesn't handle basic data types like int32_t and binary well.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)?

Comment: data = [chr(i) for i in pack('i',-(2**31))[::-1]] seems to work perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I would think simply `data = pack('!i', n)` would do it (the `!` meaning network byte order).